# como consumir webservice en azure

Tags: azure, jboss

Yo desde mi VM en azure puedo consumir de manera local un webservice sin problemas.
Ahora cuando lo quiero consumir con soapUI no llego:

desde linea de comando, con un wget me da este error:

```
$ wget http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/WSService/WSService?wsdl 
--2018-04-23 17:54:46--  http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/WSService/WSService?wsdl
Conectando con xx.xx.xx.xx:8080... falló: Conexión rehusada.
```

me estara faltando alguna regla en el firewall?

el puerto 8080 esta abierto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un detalle que note ahora es que llego al jboss en ese puerto pero no tengo permisos para por ejemplo entrar al manager así que si me falta algo que no se que seria...

la vm es un centos con jboss eap7

```
$ telnet xx.xx.xx.xx 8080
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
telnet: connect to address xx.xx.xx.xx: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Hace un tiempo me sucedió algo similiar y en mi caso se resolvió reiniciando la instancia de la VM.

Desconozco si añadir/actualizar las reglas de NSG sobre la marcha no afecta a las instancias en ejecución de manera inmediata (o que tome mucho tiempo de sincronización).

Comment: Gracias Víctor pero encontré la solución en este link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pkirchner/2016/02/02/allow-incoming-web-traffic-to-web-server-in-azure-vm/